# How to get access to my iCloud backup if I neither have access to my other iDevices nor the phone number under which it was registered?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

About a year ago, I changed my phone number but never updated it in my iCloud account to the new one. Now, I lost access to all my iDevices and I want to restore my iCloud backup to an iPhone I got from a friend.

The problem is that when I enter my iCloud e-mail and password, it says that it sent an activation code to my other iDevices - but I don't have access to them. The only other option provided is a message to my phone-number, which is the old one however that doesn't exist anymore.

I know the password of the account and I have access to the e-mail address of that iCloud account - how can I get access to it?

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a procedure called [Account Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921).  It’s considered a last resort method to access your account if you use 2FA (two factor authentication) and lost access to your devices.

> Account recovery is a process designed to get you back into your Apple ID account when you don’t have enough information to reset your password. For security reasons, it might take several days or longer before you can use your account again. We know this delay is inconvenient, but it's important so that we can keep your account and information safe.

Based on what you described, you are a prime candidate for this service.